# replace string in dataframe

Tags: r, replace, dataframe, gsub

I'm trying to replace a certain string in a large data.frame. I just found the following solution but `gsub` doesn't preserve the original data.frame layout. How can I achieve this.

I mean I want to replace a string and don't want to change the layout of the df.

Consider this example:

```
test<-data.frame(a=c("a","b","c","d"),b=c("a","e","g","h"),c=c("i","j","k","a"))
gsub("a","new",test)
```

Thx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will want to `lapply` through your `data.frame` testing for `character` or `factor` entries and then applying `gsub` appropriately. The result will be a `list`, but `as.data.frame` fixes this.

```
test$val <- 1:4 # a non character/factor variable
(test2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(test,function(x) if(is.character(x)|is.factor(x)) gsub("a","new",x) else x)))
    a   b   c val
1 new new   i   1
2   b   e   j   2
3   c   g   k   3
4   d   h new   4
class(test2$val) # to see if it is unchanged
[1] "integer"
```

Comment: why did you wrap the whole expression in brackets?

Comment: @RichardSmith That makes the expression return its result visibly to the console. Assignment is normally returned invisibly.

Answer (score 6):

```
as.data.frame(sapply(test, function(x) gsub("a", "new", x)))
```

Comment: thanks, but that gives me a character matrix, my df has numerical values too, then I run into problems when processing the data further