# gsub replaces single occurence twice

Tags: r, replace, gsub

I use the following (taken from [replace string in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540305/replace-string-in-dataframe)) to replace Spanish words "Si" or "Sí" to "Yes"

```
(CensResultsUnpivot <- as.data.frame(lapply(CensResultsUnpivot, function(x) if (is.character(x)|is.factor(x)) gsub("[Si|Sí]", "Yes", x) else x)))
```

The result I get everywhere is "YesYes" instead of "Yes" ... ?  Why?

Comment: Off-topic (and possibly irrelevant for your dataset), but in some contexts the Spanish word "si" means "if".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
  gsub("Si|Sí", "Yes", x)
```

instead of

```
 gsub("[Si|Sí]", "Yes", x)
```

When using the brackets, R replaces any of the characters "S" and "i" by "Yes", that's why you get "YesYes"

Comment: I think the above comment was in response to my now-deleted comment about how you should vectorize this too, I was going to submit an answer now so I deleted it

Comment: It works better, but still not completely: only "Si" is replaced (once), but "Sí" (with the accent) is not replaced at all... It has something to do with the special character, because if I use  "Si|No" it does replace both occurences...

Comment: I had to use \xed to represent the "Latin small letter i with acute" so it became `"Si|S\xed"`

Comment: @intrixius, well done, I didn't know the code for í. (Actually, when writing `gsub("Si|Sí", "Yes", "No Sí")` in the console, it does give me `No Yes`...)

Answer (score 2):

This is faster/better R code

```
testFrame <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:5,ncol=5,nrow=4))
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  5  4  3  2
2  2  1  5  4  3
3  3  2  1  5  4
4  4  3  2  1  5

testFrame[testFrame==1 | testFrame ==2] <- "yes"

> testFrame
   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
1 yes   5   4   3 yes
2 yes yes   5   4   3
3   3 yes yes   5   4
4   4   3 yes yes   5
```

Comment: Though this certainly would be faster, the question was about `gsub`

Comment: How does this relate to replacing characters in a string?