# Changing all values in a data frame with a data frame specifying replacement

Tags: r

I have a question that seems simple, but I can't seem to find an answer to this problem. I am trying to replace all values generated in a williams design (values 1 - 4) with a character string TRT1, TRT2, etc.

```
d = data.frame(crossdes::williams(4))
names(d) = c("Period 1", "Period 2","Period 3","Period 4")
d2 = data.frame(treatmentNo = c(1,2,3,4), 
            treatmentName = c("TRT1","TRT2",
                              "TRT3", "TRT4"))
```

I would like to have everything in d changed from values to what is specified in d2.

Thanks.

Comment: Just out of interest: Which package is the `williams()` function from?

Comment: Apologies - it is from the crossdes package. It just creates a williams design crossover (in this case, just a latin square). It results in a 4x4 matrix.

Comment: Just to clarify, so if its 1, it should be replaced by TRT1, if its 2, it should be replaced by TRT2 and so on?

Comment: have tried with [?gsub](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html)

Comment: Teja K - You are correct. Mitra - I thought about gsub, but I am not sure how to use this to replace a vector of numbers (1 - 4) with a vector of replacments (TRT1 - TRT4) in a data frame.

Comment: you can easily embed it in a function as [lapply](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html)

Comment: I've made a very quick research on SO, and come up with this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954017/r-replace-characters-using-gsub-how-to-create-a-function . (Though, the accepted answer uses `for` which I personally hate using in R) I am sure they are plenty others

Comment: Or this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540305/replace-string-in-dataframe

Comment: When you say 'everything in d' what are you referring to? d2 has two columns, 4 rows. d has 4 columns. Does it have 2 rows? Will d2 values be repeated across the entire d data frame? Are you just changing the names? You did not post the desired output for comparison or testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% mutate_each(funs(d2$treatmentName[match(.,d2$treatmentNo)]))
```

Which gives:

```
#  Period 1 Period 2 Period 3 Period 4
#1     TRT1     TRT2     TRT4     TRT3
#2     TRT2     TRT3     TRT1     TRT4
#3     TRT3     TRT4     TRT2     TRT1
#4     TRT4     TRT1     TRT3     TRT2
```

Or you could also try the `lookup()` function in the `qdapTools` package:

```
library(qdapTools)
data.frame(apply(d, 2, lookup, d2))
```

Or using base R:

```
data.frame(lapply(d, function(x) d2$treatmentName[match(x, d2$treatmentNo)]))
```

Which gives:

```
#  Period.1 Period.2 Period.3 Period.4
#1     TRT1     TRT2     TRT4     TRT3
#2     TRT2     TRT3     TRT1     TRT4
#3     TRT3     TRT4     TRT2     TRT1
#4     TRT4     TRT1     TRT3     TRT2
```

Comment: Thanks Steven, both seem to work. It's a bit surprising though that it involves downloading and installing some fairly extensive packages to do something so simple. I would have though some apply function would have worked. This works great, however.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with no external packages

```
f <- function(x) x[match(x,d2[,1])] <- d2[match(x,d2[,1]),2]

newdf <- apply(d,1,f)

newdf <- t(newdf)
```

Comment: Thanks - this seems good too, except that it wipes out the data frame, requiring it to be recreated. This is fine, it just changes the order of how I would create the data frame.